# Lvalue error when attempting to change webview.bounds.origin.x/y

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bounds

So basically, I'm trying to create an NSTimer which will scroll through a UIWebView (here named _webView). The timer is firing correctly, but the other lines are giving me an "Lvalue required as left operand of assignment" error. All I want to do is increment the y coordinate of the origin by, say, 10, every time the NSTimer fires. What's going wrong here?

```
NSLog(@"Value of webView.bounds.origin.y = %f", _webView.bounds.origin.y);
CGPoint topLeft = {_webView.bounds.origin.x, _webView.bounds.origin.y};
topLeft.y = topLeft.y + 10;
_webView.bounds.origin = topLeft;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
CGRect newRect = _webView.bounds;
newRect.origin.y += 10;
_webView.bounds = newRect;
```

Comment: This seems to be moving the entire UIWebView, as opposed to scrolling the content on it, which is what I intended to do. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I believe you have to get and set the CGRect as a whole, not just the CGPoint part.  So I'm getting the whole rect, changing just the values and setting it as a whole.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, you likely need to look at manipulating the 'contentOffset' of the webview as opposed to the actual webview bounds. Not entirely sure as I've never had to do it before - but I imagine it uses a scrollview for it's content.